# Calculation based on the value selected in the drop down list in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, drop-down-menu, dependencies, google-sheets-formula, calculation

I have a google sheet with a dependant drop down list based on the values selected in 2 different drop down list. I have managed to get the values in the dependant list but now based on the value selected I have to calculate the total amount. Example, in the below google sheet, the dependant drop down list is cell G2. This list contains the values Full, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, Not Applicable. Cell B14 and B16 are manual entries but cell B18 will calculate **(B14*B16)/G2**. The calculation will be as below. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Google Sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wbew4MA35UBp3wk2AQ1gnVdR7-88NCAZz9uB6lx7Qu8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: try: `=iferror((B16*B18)/switch(G1,"Full",1,"Not Applicable",0,left(G1)/right(G1)),"-")`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had to make some changes for the formula to work. Firstly I had to convert the drop down values format to Plain Text and then use the formula with the changes as shown below.

=iferror((B16*B18)*switch(G1,"Full",1,"Not Applicable",0, "1/4",0.25, "1/2",0.5, "3/4",0.75,left(G1)/right(G1)),"0")

Answer (score 0):

#### Try:

```
=IFERROR((B16*B18)/IFERROR(IFS(G1="Full",1,G1="Not Applicable",0),left(G1)/right(G1)),"Undefined")
```

#### Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some changes had to be made in order for the formula—provided by @rockinfreakshow in the comments—to work.

1. I had to convert the drop down values format to Plain Text
2. Changed the formula a little as shown below.

   ```
   =iferror((B16*B18)*switch(G1,"Full",1,"Not Applicable",0, "1/4",0.25, "1/2",0.5, "3/4",0.75,left(G1)/right(G1)),"0")
   ```